# PHP Inventory Management Registration

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, url-rewriting, registration

I currently have a system where you can login, and insert values into a database to manage inventory. I'm trying to figure out a way to have users able to register and have it automatically create this table for them according to their session id, and then have them re-directed to a page with options to insert data into this table. The PHP code for inserting an item into the database is:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","inventory");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }



    $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (ItemNumber, Quantity)
       VALUES
            ('".$_POST['ItemNumber']."', '".$_POST['Quantity']."' )";

     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
     {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
     }
     echo "1 record added";


    mysqli_close($con);
     ?>
```

Can I change this so instead of inserting into "orders", it inserts into the table matching the users session id? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a table matching the session id? Do you have a table named the same as the PHP session id?

Comment: Dynamic table names are a bad practice. Would you rather search one table for a specific user session, or root through potentially hundreds/thousands of session named tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good practice to create a table for each user.

Have an extra field in the orders table to denote the user who placed the order.

Table definition like this,

**UserId,ItemNumber, Quantity**

Insert Query

```
     $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (UserId,ItemNumber, Quantity)
   VALUES
        ('<UserId goes here from session data>','".$_POST['ItemNumber']."', '".$_POST['Quantity']."' )";
```

Comment: Ohhh, okay, this makes a lot of sense. thanks a ton, this should help.

Comment: Then I can just query the database for rows that match the user id, and display those to the user, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a field in ur orders table which represents id of the user who inserted the order..

**The structure of 'orders' table can be like
id primary key,
item_id int,
ordered_by user_id(foreign key)**

..